Go MySQL driver 500x slower than ADO.NET for simple select query
I wrote two programs in both golang using database/sql and github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql, and another program in C# using ADO.NET. They both run the extremely simple SELECT * FROM users query 10 times, and report how long it took.
Go takes ~500ms (yes half a second) each query, where ADO.NET takes ~500μs. Querying the database using MySQL workbench or dbeaver yields a similar result, where each select takes ~500μs - 1ms. Half a second for a select with only 10 records seems like an anomaly in the database driver, and I cannot seem to get this poor performance using any other tool.
I have a very very simple users table in a MySQL database with the following schema:
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `failed_attempts` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `security_stamp` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username_UNIQUE` (`username`)
) 

This test database only contains 10 'user' records.
Here is the Go program:
func main() {
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user:password@tcp(serveraddress:3306)/database")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        fetch(db)
    }

}


func fetch(db *sql.DB) error {
    sql := `SELECT * FROM users`

    begin := time.Now()
    
    rows, rowsErr := db.Query(sql)
    if rowsErr != nil {
        return rowsErr
    }
    fmt.Printf("Operation took %s\n", time.Since(begin))
    
    rows.Close()
    return nil

}

Here is the C# program:
static void Main()
{
    string connectionString = "server=serveraddress;uid=user;pwd=password;database=database";
    string query = "SELECT * FROM users";

    using MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Operation took {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
    
        reader.Close();
    
    }
}

Strangely, this problem goes away if I only select one column instead of *. If I execute SELECT id FROM users the query takes ~500μs-1ms to complete, just like the other benchmarks. I can add up to 5 columns to the query before it drops back down to 500ms.
To make things worse, when querying a different table containing 10000+ records, with more columns, it takes ~13ms per select *, which is significantly better than the 500ms for a simple user table with 10 records.
With more testing, running the query SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 5 takes ~1ms but SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 6 takes 500ms. This change only impacts the performance of the go program, and does not have a significant effect in the C# version.
To my knowledge, go automatically handles pooling with the db object that I created in main(), and I free connections using rows.Close(). Is there a known bug with the driver that I am unaware of? What's going on here?

In Go sql.Open "may just validate its arguments without creating a connection to the database. To verify that the data source name is valid, call DB.Ping.". So I'd suggest calling db.Ping() before entering the loop (establishing a connection may take a while and your C# code does this outside of the benchmark period). I would also suggest processing the results (otherwise you cannot be sure these were retrieved, and sometimes the only way to terminate an operation is to drop the connection).

@Brits I should have specified that the connection is successful, and data is retrieved. I removed any data processing code to eliminate as much variability as possible. I only wanted to benchmark query speed.

My point is that this will impact the test. In the C# code the connection (I believe) will come up before connection.Open() returns, in Go it attempts to connect when the first query runs (so one test includes the time to establish a connection, the other does not). Also, because you don't get the data, you don't know what you are testing (one may just send the command and return without waiting for results). The last point is that calling Close() without getting results may (not sure if the MySql driver does this) drop the connection (meaning the next Query reconnects - expensive).
